# Getting groups by group index

Tags: pandas, group-by, python-3.8

I want to access the group by group index.  My dataframe is as given below

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import numpy as np

data = """
id,name
100,A
100,B
100,C
100,D
100,pp;
212,E
212,F
212,ds
212,G
212, dsds
212, sas
300,Endüstrisi`
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data))
```

I want to groupby 'id' and access the groups by its group index.

```
dfg=df.groupby('id',sort=False,as_index=False)
dfg.get_group(0)
```

I was expecting this to return the first group which is the group for `id =1` (which is the first group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need pass value of `id`:

```
dfg=df.groupby('id',sort=False)
a = dfg.get_group(100)

print (a)
    id name
0  100    A
1  100    B
2  100    C
3  100    D
4  100  pp;
```

---

```
dfg=df.groupby('id',sort=False)
a = dfg.get_group(df.loc[0, 'id'])

print (a)
    id name
0  100    A
1  100    B
2  100    C
3  100    D
4  100  pp;
```

If need enumerate groups is possible use [`GroupBy.ngroup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html):

```
dfg=df.groupby('id',sort=False)
a = df[dfg.ngroup() == 0]

print (a)
    id name
0  100    A
1  100    B
2  100    C
3  100    D
4  100  pp;
```

**Detail**:

```
print (dfg.ngroup())
0     0
1     0
2     0
3     0
4     0
5     1
6     1
7     1
8     1
9     1
10    1
11    2
dtype: int64
```

EDIT: Another idea is if need select groups by positions (all id are consecutive groups) with compare by unique values of `id` selected by positions:

```
ids = df['id'].unique()
print (ids)
[100 212 300]

print (df[df['id'].eq(ids[0])])
    id name
0  100    A
1  100    B
2  100    C
3  100    D
4  100  pp;

print (df[df['id'].eq(ids[1])])
     id   name
5   212      E
6   212      F
7   212     ds
8   212      G
9   212   dsds
10  212    sas
```

Comment: I don't want to access by the `id`. I want to access by the group index. I believe that when we group, it will generate unique index for each group, right (0,1,2,...). I want to access by that group index.

Comment: @Shew - I think `ngroup` like last solution?

Comment: loc based solution gives me error `TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed` What could be wrong ?

Comment: @Shew - I guess multiple `0` index values

Comment: @Shew - I think error means `df.loc[0, 'id']` return not scalar, but `Series`, because multiple `0` index values. For prevent is use `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)` before solution.

Comment: I was trying to compare the efficiency. `%timeit a = dfg.get_group(df.loc[0, 'id'])`   `545 µs ± 911 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)`   `%timeit a = df[dfg.ngroup() == 0]`  `10.2 ms ± 333 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)`. There is huge difference. loc based solution is much much faster.

Comment: @Shew - hmmm, but why not use `df = df[df['id'] == df.loc[0, 'id']]` ?

Comment: In that way, how can I access my second group? I want to sample some group index (I got around 100k groups and sampling around 4 or 5 groups) and then plot data for those specific groups only.

Comment: @Shew - Added to answer.